# Having two "param" in one template

Tags: html, css, xslt-1.0

I wonder two know that is it possible to bring two `param` inside template? and if so how? For example as this one:

```
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="timeParam"/>
    <xsl:param name="withYear"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dateParam" select="substring-before($timeParam,'T')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($dateParam,1,4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($dateParam,6,2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($dateParam,9,2)"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($day) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($month) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$month"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($withYear) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="withYear" select="$year" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and calling:

```
<xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:with-param name="timeParam" select="attribute::time"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="withYear" select="1"/>                    
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:with-param name="timeParam" select="attribute::time"/> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

As you see in some position I need year parameter and in others not.

Ps. The reason to use two parameter is that I do not want to duplicate the code.

Comment: @PhilRoss but it does not help me more. I need to pass the `select` part!!

Comment: Your question is not clear. A template can have as many parameters as you want. If you don't pass a parameter when calling the template, the default value (defined within the template) will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly your question is. I am quite sure your named template needs to be changed, because you cannot have `xsl:with-param` as child of `xsl:if`.

I think that instead of:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($withYear) = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="withYear" select="$year" />
</xsl:if>
```

you should have:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($withYear) = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
</xsl:if>
```

or simply:

```
<xsl:if test="$withYear">
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. such a mistake that I did. You're totally right.